# Excel Formulas need explanation

Tags: c#, excel, web, formula

I'm working on an Excel sheet to convert it to website and there are a lot of calculations some of them need explanation

```
INDEX (A:A;MATCH(1;IF(A:A<>0;IF(A:A<>"";1));0))
```

What I thought about this one is: it will return last value of last cell contains value 
but when try to do it programmatically it returns another values than the excel !

What the difference between the  above formula and this one :

```
LOOKUP(9.99E+307;A:A)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried googling the VBA functions (`INDEX`, `LOOKUP`, etc).  There's **plenty** of information on these on the net.

Comment: yup in many many ways and the conclusion was what i wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula will only work as array formula

```
{=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,IF(A:A<>0,IF(A:A<>"",1)),0))}
```

and it gets then the value of the first not empty cell in column A which is not equal 0.

The formula

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A:A)
```

gets the last value in column A which is numeric.

To get the value of the last not empty cell in column A you could use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

I have used English(USA) version of formulas with comma as formula separator. As i have seen in the question is semicolon used as formula separator. So this depends on the locale versions of Excel and have to be changed depending on this.

Comment: Thank you to correct my thought , it was totally wrong !